# Ruby on Rails: Cucumber: how do I Rake a single feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Reason why I want to run them individually, is because I need to have them individually set up in my Rake file, because, My Java Heap Space fills up when I run them all together

Comment: Java Heap Space? How does Java figure into this if you're using a Rake/Rails/Cucumber stack?

Comment: running on jruby, i'm guessing

Comment: not directly. I'm using some libraries along with cucumber that use jruby though. I think CapyBara is one. =\

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To answer the Rake question directly, you can use:

```
rake FEATURE=features/adding_products.feature cucumber
```

but the [Using Rake](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/using-rake) wiki page advises against using rake for anything but on a CI server because it's slower to start.  Just use the cucumber command line instead, i.e.:

```
cucumber features/adding_products.feature
```

or, if you must:

```
bundle exec cucumber features/adding_products.feature
```

Comment: for new version, you can do this too - bundle exec cucumber features/adding_products.feature

Answer (score 68):

The correct way is to run it using the `cucumber` executable if you're using Rails 2, or `bundle exec cucumber` if you're using Rails 3 (and thus Bundler).

To run a specific feature:

```
[command] features/signing_in.feature
```

To run a specific scenario from that feature:

```
[command] features/signing_in.feature:6
```

The line number can be any line inside that feature, but is usually the first line.

If you run `rake cucumber:ok` and some scenarios fail, at the bottom of the output you will see something like this:

```
cucumber features/sigining_in.feature:6 # Signing in via form
```

You can triple-click this line and paste it into your terminal to just run that scenario.

Comment: To run a single scenario, you can also type this:
`cucumber --name "Signing in via form"`

Comment: Thank you Ryan and Bastien. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 37):

The rake did not worked for me.
Just replaced the rake with bundle exec, and it worked.
below is a sample.

**bundle exec cucumber features/users/signup.feature --require features**

Comment: Worked for me too. If I omit the --require features cucumber failed to identify the step definitions.

Comment: right, had the same problem. the alternative apparently is to hard code that `--require features` replacig this line in **config/cucumber.yml** `std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags ~@wip"`
with `std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags ~@wip --require features/"`
see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264030/rake-runs-all-my-cucumber-tests-fine-but-cucumber-doesnt-have-the-steps)

Comment: Note: "Any feature that is located inside a sub-directory of features directory must require features [--require features]." Per https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Running-Features

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure cucumber's [tag feature](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags) was available when the question asked, but i prefer setting `@active` tag

```
  @active
  Feature ..
```

or

```
  @active
  Scenario ..
```

and

```
  cucumber --tags @active
```

Answer (score 13):

I like the short command `$ cucumber -n`.

If:

```
Feature: Manage Contents
  In order to manage instances from custom content types
  …
```

Then:

```
$ cucumber -n "Manage Contents"
```

Comment: Good one Buddy, you are the Genius

Answer (score 4):

To run a single feature file.

```
cucumber /project folder/features/featurefile.feature
```

To run particular scenario:

```
cucumber /project folder/features/featurefile.feature:10
```

> where 10 is the line of scenario.

If you use bundler,

`bundle exec cucumber /project folder/features/featurefile.feature`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `script/cucumber` to do individual files.

Assuming you are in the root directory of your project and you have a features folder:

```
./script/cucumber features/adding_products.feature
```

Edit: After re-reading your question, are you looking to do individual features, or scenarios?

Comment: For me, this works `cucumber -r features features/adding_products.feature`

Answer (score 0):

If you use cuke4duke you can run this separately from ant or maven.

The [manual](http://wiki.github.com/aslakhellesoy/cuke4duke/command-line) states that you can use the same options as cucumber. So I would expect you can pas the filename of the feature you want to run on the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters generally required when you have multiple cucumber projects in a large scale enterprise are
1) where to run the tests
2) Which environment to run against
3) Which browser
4) What tags

Below is a pattern that is very flexible and can be used in multiple ways based on your needs.
This pattern can be used to run locally, against a selenium grid, against saucelabs and in a continuous integration environment

http://seleniumframework.wordpress.com/2014/05/18/pattern-for-running-multiple-cucumber-projects-on-ci-server/